# Dynamic Memory Allocation query

Tags: recursion, memory, memory-management, compilation

As we know

- Dynamic memory allocation uses heap area.
- To implement recursion we will need a stack.

So can we say that to implement recursion,we will not require dynamic memory allocation?

I am totally confused.!

Comment: The best is to show some code or the thing you want to achieve for further explainations. About your question, I want to say that it necessarily need some stack and the necessity to allocate some memory in the heap depends on what you want to do in your recursion loop.

Comment: Heap and stack are actually implementation details associated with particular environments.   Dynamic memory allocation means the program can explicitly allocate, use, and later release memory.    All function calls (unless inlined) require some means to track context so the function can return and execution then continues from the call point - and recursion just means that the tracking of context can handle a function, directly or indirectly, calling itself.  So the concepts of dynamic memory allocation and recursion are actually distinct from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion itself only requires the stack. To implement a recursive factorial method, for example

```
int fact(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    return n * fact(n - 1);
}
```

only requires the stack. Push `n - 1`, call `fact` on it, and then multiply the result (which will probably returned also on the stack) by `n`. But even though the act of recursion itself does not require dynamic memory, the *algorithm* you are implementing via recursion might involve tasks that require dynamic memory. So no implementing recursion itself might not require dynamic memory, but the problem you are using recursion to solve might need it.

Comment: okk.considering your code,size of 'n' is unknown at the time of compilation.It will be known at the run time and hence at the runtime,it will be decided that how many activation record will be created .so shouldn't it is like a dynamic memory allocation ?

Comment: No, because the program does not decide how many activation records are needed beforehand, it just creates one each time `fact` is called. It's not "dynamic" memory allocation  because the stack is static memory i.e. it is a fixed region of your program's memory. It can grow and shrink at one end as activation records are added and removed, but it is confined to a fixed area of the program's memory pre-allocated for it. It cannot be released and then re-allocated somewhere else like dynamic memory can.

Comment: okk .got your point that stack grows at one end(LIFO order)according tho the value of n.But i have only 1 doubt.My doubt is that there are 2 type of memory allocation .a)static memory allocation . b)dynamic memory allocation ...Now consider the case of recursion which requires stack.So this falls under dynamic memory allocation ..right ?